# Multiple files download using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, server, download

I am trying to download multiple files using PHP. I know it can only be done by using a zip archive, but I dont want all the directories and subdirectories to be included in the downloaded folder, I just need the files.

I tried using "basename()" but it wont download anything when I do that, following is my code.

I also tried making a new array of just the filenames extracted by using "basename()", but it wont download still.

```
        if ( extension_loaded( 'zip' ) ) {
        $zipFolder = new ZipArchive();
        $zipName = time().".zip";

        if ( $zipFolder->open( $zipName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE ) !== TRUE ) {
            echo "Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
        }

        foreach ( $filepathArray as $f ) {
            $zipFolder->addFile($f);
        }

        $zipFolder->close();

        if ( file_exists( $zipName ) ) {
            header( 'Content-type: application/zip' );
            header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $zipName . '"' );
            readfile( $zipName );
            unlink( $zipName );
        }
    }
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6kn0.png) is my dashboard screenshot:

As you can see the path it quite long, hence I don't need all those folders, I just need the files.

Comment: I think you should go about this a bit different. Instead of giving the whole directory as the handle instead loop through the remote directory and only return files that you want. Then pass that as an array of file handles to your zip library.

Answer (score -3):

HTTP doesn't support multiple files in a single download. So make base page with a javascript timeout that redirects the user to each of the files, one at a time.

Example:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var file_list = new Array(
      'http://www.example.com/filename1.file',
      'http://www.example.com/filename2.file',
      'http://www.example.com/filename3.file'
    );
    for (var i=0; i < file_list.length - 1; i++) {
      setTimeout(function () {
         document.location = file_list[i];
      }, i * 1000);
    }
    </script>

    <h1>Please wait</h1>
    <p>Your download will start in a moment.</p>
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It's not PHP and there is a big difference between making the user download the file and having the server do it.